Recreating MIT AI Lab document style
I'm quite new on this StackExchange site. I have been using LaTeX recently, and got myself into a situation where I want to write a memorandum (or just memo). I work in computer sciences and mathematics so I want to try out LaTeX for rendering and equations (it seems nicer to use than Words), but I have no experiment in designing or modifying titles and document elements. I have been looking around and found out this memo style of Rodney A. Brooks, which looks pretty nice:

It seems nice enough, the font is especially good, and the layout, for example, the author listing is very of my liking. But currently I can't reproduce such.
Can someone help me recreating this document style, maybe also the fonts, but mainly the style of it? If possible, can you provide me with guidances and resources on how to recreate documents and design my own template like this? Thanks a lot!
PS: Why the document look so "old" and blurry? Is that an effect?

This font is Computer Modern Roman, and it comes with LaTeX. Most of your basic document classes will use this font by default. The original Computer Modern was a raster font, and considering that the document is dated from 1991, this could be one of several reasons why it doesn't have the vector version of the font.

I'm curious, are you looking for a tutorial to create a document in LaTeX, and is this your first time? If you haven't used LaTeX before, instead of asking here, you may find it more helpful to start with one of the many online tutorials on LaTeX. You're welcome to come back once you've tried something and have a specific problem where you've gotten stuck! The Not So Short Introduction to LaTeX is a good starting place, and there's a Japanese version too if you're willing to convert Postscript to PDF.

@gz839918 thanks for that! But I know how to use LaTeX, at least elementarily, and for now I kind of want to have a template that looks like that, but in a very short time (since I have to submit my memo), but again still want to help myself learning... quite a dilemma for me.

Welcome. // Not exactly the one you look for, but a close match: https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/tech-report-ala-mit-ai-lab-1981/rgwpsrgzjpxr . If you inspect it, you'll get the idea. However, you better would use the \begin{titlepage} ... environment to typeset the first page. // If you are in a hurry, enter the title-info first and care later for alignement, font size etc. Use Latex standard fonts, together with \large, Large etc.

Oh, thank you so much! I will check it right now (I really need it quick, the font and typeset is really preferences).

Just to show you, it's not that difficult:

type content first
tweak look and placement later (or whenever it suits you)


1. titlepage environment
Type in there, whatever you feel needs to be communicated. This was more or less my procedure:

enter all texts, with one linebreak
encapsulate with \textbf{}, \large{}, center environments etc.
introduce vertical spacings

Herein, \newcommand\vdist[1]{\vspace{\stretch{#1}}} does some magic: it separates the various texts in a relative manner. This can be nice, if e.g. the abstract varies in length. E.g. in my code below they separate in ratios 0.1 : 0.2 : 0.2 : 1 : 1 : 0.2 . Of course, there are many other ways to do vertical placements with Latex. E.g. you might want constant vertical spacings in the upper part until author: substitute e.g. \vspace{12pt} etc. for \vdist{..} there.
2. Rest of document
2-col layout, as in the reference you linked to, using any Latex standard (or packages) as usual.
3. Outlook
You may want to save the whole titlepage environment e.g. in titl.tex, and just put \input{titl} before \twocolumn.
There are several ways to deal with variable content in the titlepage from memo to memo, like:

editing titl.tex directly
defining \newcommands e.g. for memo-number AND redefining it in your main document like \renewcommand\memonr{456-A} etc.
turning the whole thing into your own documentclass (like aimemo)
etc.
it all depends on the requency of changes/submissions

Some comments on to the Overleaf template
They use packages titling and abstract, which are, if I found out correctly, about 15 years old. Their main advantage are several predfined macros ... you can define whatever is needed via \newcommand, too. E.g. to reuse this .tex code, memo number, date, etc. are variable, and you'd define some macros for these constants. (This is a matetr of preference: you can also edit the written text in the titlepage section)
Something you certainly want to do is using package geometry, e.g. to adjust papersize, margins etc.

\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\vdist[1]{\vspace{\stretch{#1}}}

% ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
\begin{document}

% ~~~ titlepage ~~~~~~~~
\begin{titlepage}
\parindent0pt{
 % ~~~ Institution ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{center}
  \large{\uppercase{your university\\  
  for whatever you are going to do}}
 \end{center}

 % ~~~ type and date of document ~~~~~~~
 \vdist{.1}
 A.I Memo No. 1293\hfill April,1991

 % ~~~ title, author etc. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \begin{center}
  \vdist{.2}
  {\huge{\textbf{Intelligence Without Reason}}}
 
  \vdist{.2}
  {\large{\textbf{Rodney A. Brooks}}}
 
  Prepared for \textit{Computers and Thoughts}, IJCAI-91
 \end{center}

 % ~~~ abstract ~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \vdist{1}
 \begin{abstract}
  \textit{Computers and Thoughts} \lipsum[1]
 \end{abstract}

 % ~~~ copyright and disclaimer ~~~~~~~~~~~~
 \vdist{1}
 \begin{center}
  Copyright \copyright Your University, 1991
 \end{center}
 
 \vdist{.2}
 This report describes. \lipsum[10]
}

\end{titlepage}

\clearpage
% ~~~ and now: the rest of your document ~~~~~~~
\twocolumn

\section{Introduction}
\lipsum[1-2]

\subsection{Approaches}
\lipsum[4-5]

\subsection{Outline}
\lipsum[5,5]

\end{document}

